# Did Lucy activate the dog's brain capacity?

Tags: lucy

When Lucy made contact with the dog at the airport, she looked intently into the dog's eyes. I'm thinking that perhaps this was a connection part to the dog? But if she made a connection to it then the dog would soon also have 100% brain capacity since the brain of the dog is probably smaller than Lucy's, the dog would then reach 100% more quickly, evolve and be "everywhere" before her.

**Is it reasonable that both Lucy and the dog are actually *both* "everywhere"?**

[image]

Comment: The only notion I get from that scene is she "tells" the dog "don't even go there and back off".

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that just because Lucy scared the dog, now the dog have the same power as Lucy?? it makes no sense. It's not like she gave the drugs to the dog. Believe it or not, dogs can sense things that humans cannot, Ceaser Milan uses the term "energy"

Answer (score 3):

After having reviewed the script, I see no evidence that Lucy gave the drug sniffer dog anything other than a mild electrical stimulus (a jolt) in order to scare it away.

> **A sniffer dog ambles over.**
>
> **DEL RIO**:  *Okay... What form are the drugs in? Bars? Capsules?*
>
> **LUCY**: *Powder. In plastic packets hidden in their intestines. Make sure they don't split open when you take them out.*
>
> **DEL RIO:** *Pardon me?*
>
> **Lucy lowers her dark glasses.**
>
> **The dog recoils, its tail between its legs. Lucy nudges her glasses back up her nose.**

A few minutes later, we see her do very much the same to the flight attendant who tells her to put her computer away:

> **FLIGHT ATTENDANT**: *Miss, I have to ask you to put away your computers now.*
>
> Lucy is engrossed in the thousands of items of coded information
> scrolling past her eyes. It's illegible for any normal human being.
>
> **FLIGHT ATTENDANT:** *Miss?*
>
> **LUCY:** (riveted to the screen) *You should wipe your nose.*
>
> The Flight Attendant doesn't understand.
>
> **A drop of blood appears in one nostril.** The woman touches her nose and
> realizes she's bleeding. Slightly flustered, she scurries away. Lucy
> keeps working.